# Handle materialsearchbar search results in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using `com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:+` dependency in my app to search data in my SQLite database. It does load suggestions based on the data i have in the database but when a user clicks on one of the suggestion and confirms it by clicking the search icon in the keyboard nothing gets displayed, the adapter is not being called to display the result. below is my search activity

```
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hyme_list);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    materialSearchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);

    database = new Database(this);

    materialSearchBar.setHint("Search here");
    materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
    loadSuggestList();

    materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            List<String> sugest = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String search: suggestList) {
                if (search.toUpperCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toUpperCase()))
                    sugest.add(search);

            }
                materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(sugest);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
            if (!enabled){

                searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getBaseContext(),database.getSongs());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

            startSearch(text.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {


        }
    });


    searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getSongs());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

}

private void startSearch(String text) {

    searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getSongByName(text));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

}

private void loadSuggestList() {
    suggestList = database.getTitle();
    materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);

}
```

Comment: you should show suggestions inside **afterTextChanged** methods

Comment: `List<String> sugest=new ArrayList<>();` can't access from `afterTextChanged`

Comment: move the whole code of onTextChanged inside afterTextChanged.

Comment: that didn't solve the problem. i just tried it

Comment: try to put log inside **onSearchStateChanged** and **onSearchConfirmed** see if it is getting call

Comment: @RahulKhurana i just did that and `onSearchConfirmed` is been called but I don't know why the adapter don't show

Comment: May be **getSongByName** isn't returning values

Comment: Thank you for your ideas i just fixed it. the problem was in my `getSongByName` function it had an error

Comment: glad to know :)